# Deserialize XML with serde-xml-rs creates Err(duplicate field `$value`)

Tags: xml, rust, serde

[This](https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=25555558&retmode=xml) is an example of the xml schema I am attempting to parse.  Only a few fields are of interest to me. The root of the schema is the `PubmedArticleSet` which contains >= 0 `PubmedArticle` entries.  I am interested in the fields contained in those entries.  I am getting the error in the title, though I do not see the problem associated with that error [here](https://github.com/RReverser/serde-xml-rs/issues/55).

```
<PubmedArticle>
  <MedlineCitation>
     <PMID>xxxxxxxx</PMID>
     <date tags i don't care about/>
     <other date tags i don't care about/>
     <Article>
       <tags I don't care about/>
         <children I don't care about>  
       <other tags I don't care about/>
         <children I don't care about>
       <AuthorList>
         <Author>
           <LastName>xxxx</LastName>
           <FirstName>i don't care about this</FirstName>
           <Initials>xx</Initials>
           <AffiliationInfo>
              <Affiliation>String of text</Affiliation>
           </AffiliationInfo>
          </Author>
          <Author>same as above</Author>
        </AuthorList>
        <Lots of stuff I don't care about/>
      </Article>
      <More stuff I don't care about/>
    </MedlineCitation>
    <Final stuff I don't care about/>
  </PubmedArticle>
```

And I have set up the following structs:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct PubmedArticleSet {
    #[serde(rename="$value")]
    pub articleset: Vec<PubmedArticle>
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct PubmedArticle {
    #[serde(rename="$value")]
    pub medlinecitation: MedlineCitation,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct MedlineCitation {
    #[serde(rename="$value")]
    pub pmid: PMID,
    pub article: Article
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct PMID {
    #[serde(rename="$value")]
    pub id: String
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Article {
    pub authorlist: AuthorList,
    pub publicationtypelist: Vec<PublicationType>
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct PublicationType {
    #[serde(rename="$value")]
    pub publicationtype: String
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct AuthorList {
    #[serde(rename="$value")]
    pub authorlist: Vec<Author>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Author {
    #[serde(rename="$value")]
    pub author: (LastName, Initials),
    pub affiliation: Affiliation
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct LastName {
    #[serde(rename="$value")]
    pub lastname: String
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Initials {
    #[serde(rename="$value")]
    pub initials: String
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Affiliation {
    #[serde(rename="$value")]
    pub affiliation: String
```

And I try to parse with the following function:

```
fn deser_article_records(result: &String) -> Result<PubmedArticleSet, Box<Error>> {
    if let Some(start) = result.find("<PubmedArticleSet>") {
        let records = serde_xml_rs::deserialize(result[start..].as_bytes())?;
        Ok(records)
    } else {
        Err("no articleset found")?
    }
}
```

Comment: That comment is not useful. I provided a link to the full xml but that is quite a long document. I abbreviated the xml with pseudotags indicating what was relevant. What would you suggest I have done differently?

Comment: I would suggest providing *syntactically valid* XML. Note that links to offsite resources are specifically what that off-topic reason is all about. Those have no guarantee of being around when the next person comes to this question. That's why you are supposed to put the shortest code necessary *into* the question. Check out what a [MCVE] is. For example, you could probably *remove* all of those tags and a whole bunch of your Rust code and reduce the entire question down to 20 lines of XML and a small handful of structs, and a complete driver program including imports, etc.

Comment: As it is now, your question requires any answerer to do **a lot** of additional legwork to even reproduce the exact error.

Comment: Possibly this? https://github.com/RReverser/serde-xml-rs/issues/55

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you have XML elements with other things in between. You don't show an example in the above snippet, but for instance:

```
<Author ...>
<SomethingElse ...>
<Author>
```

serde_xml_rs appears to want all tags to be adjacent per this comment: https://github.com/RReverser/serde-xml-rs/issues/55

i.e.

```
<Author...>
<Author...>
<SomethingElse ...>
```

If your XML isn't like that, you can solve this by using an `Enum`.

e.g.

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Article {
    details: Vec<Detail>
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
enum Detail {
    Author(Author),
    SomethingElse(SomethingElse)
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Author {
    ...
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct SomethingElse {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have moved on from the project and have not yet tested your suggestion. I think your diagnosis of the root problem is correct. When I have a chance to implement your solution if it solves the issue then I will mark your solution as correct. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you. I would only add that there is `#[serde(rename="$value")]` attribute needed above `Article.details` property.